# How to take a screenshot using a keyboard shortcut on an android device?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, screenshots, keyboard-shortcuts

I find using the power-button + down-volume button extremely cumbersome especially when taking time sensitive screenshots.

Is it possible to do this using a shortcut key on a bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: If the timing is crucial I recommend to connect the phone to a PC and enable develop mode + adb on the device. In `adb shell` you can execute the `screencap <filename>` command exactly when you need a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [Button Mapper app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton&hl=en_US)
2. decide a key to use to take screenshots(which you don't use usually).
3. Open the key mapper app and record the key in it(the UI is self explanatory)
4. Set the function of the key to take screenshots. Done

PS - remember to turn battery optimization off for the app otherwise if the system closes the app then no hardware buttons will work and you'll have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

There's `prtscr` button on physical keyboard that you can use to screenshot.